# How can I implement a parallax in wordpress without a plugin? , the image is in a custom field

Tags: wordpress

I want to know how I can implement a parallax effect on my page, upload the image into a custom input field. Thank you very much

Comment: Well, you will likely need to do some restructuring on your templates and add some javascript. I am not sure where to start answering this, without going into a 10-pages reply

Comment: jaja, i have a javascript template, when i upload the image only with css, the parallax is perfect, but i need take the image from a custom field, so i don't know how do i do this, can you help me?, if your need check the template ,tell me. Thanks

Comment: Add the needed custom field to the post-type use it with the_field()
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Comment: i'm going to look the link and test the solution. Thanks